# Node EventEmitter Not Giving Anticipated Results

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have a `book.js` and `server.js` file. I run `node ./server.js` and the server begins to run. I open Google Chrome and open developer console, and inpute book.rate(10), and my emit does not happen anywhere. Maybe I am not understanding eventemitters. The error is "`Uncaught Reference error: book is not defined`"

Server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var BookClass = require('./book.js');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World\n');
var book = new BookClass();
book.on('rated', function() {
 console.log('rated '  + book.getPoints());
}); 
}).listen(9000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9000/');
```

Book.js

```
var util = require("util");
var events = require("events");
var Class = function() { };
util.inherits(Class, events.EventEmitter);
Class.prototype.ratePoints = 0;
Class.prototype.rate = function(points) {
   ratePoints = points;
   this.emit('rated');
};
Class.prototype.getPoints = function() {
   return ratePoints;
}
module.exports = Class;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `book is not defined` because you haven't defined `book` on the client side, you have only defined it on the *server side*.

You cannot magically access server-side variables like that from the browser without some sort of extra library/code to provide that kind of functionality.

Comment: This makes sense, but how would the client then tell the server to give a book rating? I would imagine this would need to be inplace to update a database.

Comment: You could use something like [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/docs/) for that. You wouldn't even need the custom EventEmitter in that case, you could just send messages from the client and you execute the corresponding logic/function on the server-side.

Comment: So you have to define all variables in both files in nodejs?